# Workflow Get value from web service response

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have called a web service in SP designer and the response is something like

```
{
  "odata.metadata": "https://cloud.sharepoint.com/sites//_api/$metadata#SP.ListData.ParametersList",
  "value": [
    {
      "odata.type": "SP.Data.ParametersList",
      "odata.id": "XXXX-XXXX-XX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX",
      "odata.etag": "\"2\"",
      "odata.editLink": "Web/Lists(guid'XXXXX-XXXX-XXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX')/Items(30)",
      "FileSystemObjectType": 0,
      "Id": 30,
      "ContentTypeId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "Title": "targetTitle",
      "Value": "targetgetvalue_123",
      "ID": 24,
      "Modified": "2015-12-29T07:45:26Z",
      "Created": "2015-12-30T07:45:13Z",
      "AuthorId": 20,
      "EditorId": 20,
      "OData__UIVersionString": "1.0",
      "Attachm>ents": false,
      "GUID": "XXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXX"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to use **Get value from dictionary** in SharePoint designer to obtain Value
, but the result is not as expected. How to get the Value. i.e  (`targetgetvalue_123`).

Comment: Have you noticed url is wrong, after sites its double slash.

Comment: I have removed a subsite location manually. something sites/subsite/_api

Answer (score 0):

It`s bit tricky. Here is sample from designer:

```
Get d/results([%Variable: index%])/ID from Variable: JsonResult (Output to Variable: OutID )
```

index is just number from 0 to *Item count*